# Really confused about input functions like fgets/scanf to assign a structure pointer to a value

Tags: c, structure

Really struggling with the segments below with regards to using input functions like fgets/scanf to assign a structure pointer to a value.

What this code hopes to achieve is:
Test Case 1:
Enter names (firstName lastName):
James Lim
Enter account number:
123
Enter balance:
6789.89
Customer record:
 James Lim 123 6789.89
Enter names (firstName lastName):
End Customer <- input to quit instance (not an issue i am struggling with, just haven't add the code yet)

Can't get the code to run properly and I think the issue is with the assignment of the values of the inputs to the structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct account
    struct
    {
        char lastName[10];
        char firstName[10];
    } names;
    int accountNum;
    double balance;
};

void nextCustomer(struct account *acct);
void printCustomer(struct account acct);

int main()
{
    struct account record;
    int flag = 0;

    do {
        nextCustomer(&record);
        if ((strcmp(record.names.firstName, "End") == 0) &&
            (strcmp(record.names.lastName, "Customer") == 0))
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (flag != 1)
        {
            printCustomer(record);
        }
    } while(flag != 1);
}
```

I am struggling with the next few lines of codes below.

```
void nextCustomer(struct account *acct)
{
    int i;
    char temporary[20];

    printf("Enter names (firstName lastName) :\n");
    scanf("%s", acct->names.firstName);
    scanf("%s", acct->names.lastName);

    printf("Enter account number: \n");
    scanf("%d", acct->accountNum);

    printf("Enter balance: \n");
    scanf("%f", acct->balance);
}


void printCustomer(struct account acct)
{
    printf("%s %s %d %.2lf", acct.names.firstName, acct.names.lastName, acct.accountNum, acct.balance);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: I assume your code isn't doing what you expect but you forgot to tell us what is going wrong

Comment: BTW: Never - like in never ever - use `%s` in `scanf` The big buffer-overflow monster will come haunt you. (hint: `%9s`)

Comment: `scanf("%f", acct->balance)` leads to *undefined behavior*. `acct->balance` is a `double` which means you need to use the `%lf` Format specifier. `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: Did you check the warnings from your compiler? Or did you just ignore them?

Comment: if you followed the simple rule "TREAT ALL WARNINGS AS ERRORS" you could have solved this in 10 sec

Comment: `scanf("%d", acct->accountNum);` produced a warning

Comment: `scanf("%f", acct->balance);`produced a warning

Comment: No, it's `scanf("%lf", &acct->balance)` for the `double` type.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help given. The issue was scanf(..., acct -> ...) should have been scanf(..., &acct -> ...) with the address operator. Thank you for all the help given!